# Commutative Algebra and Monomial orders

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So whenever we are doing any problem related to ideals in the polynomial ring  $k[x_{1},x_{2},\dots x_{n}]$,(e.g. calculating a grobner basis for instance or doing the division algorithm for a set of polynomials) every questions says "fix a monomial order". So does this mean that for different monomial orders we get different solutions? (Sorry if this question seems quite trivial and blatantly obvious but I am generally not good with "visualising" such stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fix a monomial order" means:
 what authors say is true for **arbitrary**  *monomial order*. We can use the same proof strategy for any *monomial order*, but it should *not changed* hereafter.

---

This happens in abundance in math. For example:
[image]

Comment: So you mean to say, regardless of whatever monomial order we fix, the solution will always be the same?

Comment: yes. thats what i mean.